# Error in colSums(assay(sce)) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: rna-seq, r

I am having a `SingleCellExperiment` (sce) object:

> sce <- SingleCellExperiment(list(counts=UMI_count))

which has two dimensions:

```
dim(sce)
[1] 46761 68027
```

When I am trying to get column sums for all rows the following does not work:

```
colSums(assay(sce), na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)
```

Giving me an error:

> Error in colSums(assay(sce)) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Apparently the issue was already described:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/100954/

However, I can not find the solution. Is there another way of getting sums of columns of either `SingleCellExperiment` object or just `dgcMatrix`?

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of the rows or the columns?

Comment: Did you check what does `assay(sce)` return? Which is the output of `dim(assay(sce))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I just implemented it manually with the precursor to `SingleCellExperiment` matrix (`UMI_count` which is `dgcMatrix` type) object in the following way:

```
# Removing genes with 0 - counts in all of the columns
num_removed = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(UMI_count)) {
  idx = i - num_removed
  if(sum(UMI_count[idx,]) < 1) {
    UMI_count <- UMI_count[-idx,]
    num_removed = num_removed + 1
    print(i)
  }
}

sce <- SingleCellExperiment(list(counts=UMI_count))
```

I am getting sums of the columns for each row and then filtering out rows with the `sum < 1`. So, `sum` function for the slices - rows (`numeric` type) is working.